# Can't connect to remote SSH server, port 2222

Tags: macos, ssh, port, sftp

I have problem with connection to remote server via SFTP from my MacOS, tested in FileZilla. Terminal SSH connection with same user&name (or key) works correctly.

```
open "user@server_ip 
server_ip" 2222 
Error: Can't connect to remote server
```

User&password are okay, my IP address and ISP are okay (tested on another machine with same local IP address).

On server there is no attempt to login from my machine, so it fails somewhere before remote server. How to test where is the problem?

I've found [How to detect if a network is blocking outgoing ports?](https://superuser.com/questions/1336054/how-to-detect-if-a-network-is-blocking-outgoing-ports), command

```
time nmap -p 2222 portquiz.net
```

returns me

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2222/tcp open  EtherNetIP-1

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.23 seconds
nmap -p 2222 portquiz.net  0,15s user 0,02s system 62% cpu 0,267 total
```

How to solve that? What to try now?

Thanks.

Comment: Nmap suggests that outgoing port 2222 isn't blocked, plus you're saying you can connect fine to the same port on the same server IP through terminal ssh... so the problem lies with the client. FileZilla's output is weird though, it should be like `open "user@server_ip" 2222`. Is this just a typo from your part?

Comment: @AndroidX Thanks for you comment! It looks like https://snipboard.io/97rEli.jpg In Filezilla it looks good too https://snipboard.io/UcIh42.jpg I have here another SFTP in Filezilla (different server, different ports, successfully login) and in 'history' there is doubled server_ip too. It seems like a FileZilla feature.

Comment: Please change to English, then `Edit > Settings > Debug > Debug information in message log: 4`, then attempt to connect to the server and paste here the debug output.

Comment: @AndroidX https://snipboard.io/nm6P9F.jpg, I've just changed IP to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and 2x 'xxx' on line 5

Comment: @AndroidX F***, I have ip really inserted twice there (it wasn't visible in text input in FileZilla)! Really appreciate your help and showing me FileZilla debug mode! Fixed. Big THANK YOU.