# Is it possible to connect to remote 465 via own 443 port?

Tags: networking, email, firewall, openssl, smtp

I have asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1773262/how-do-i-detect-if-my-firewall-is-blocking-certain-ports?noredirect=1#comment2763788_1773262) and am opening a new question as per SE policy.

The remote SMTP server can be connected to via its own 465 port.

However, I want to reach that server via a cloud server. [This SE answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/584677/is-blocking-smtp-ports-prevent-server-from-sending-emails) says, that both the sender and the receiver server communicates via port 25. But I want this:

Cloud server :--------> reach mail Server at port 465 :-----------------> Reach reciever mail address.

The second bridge is where both servers will communicate over port 25, that is clear. But in the first bridge, do I need port 465 open? Or is there a way for me to bypass port 465, yet send the `EHLO` and `MAIL FROM` commands to the mail server?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the remote server? If so, I think you could use SSH port forwarding to do this. Look at the `-L` and `-R` options in SSH.

Comment: i  have ssh to cloud server., not to the mail server